# Why my dark mode is not working fully?while some area is working

Tags: javascript

I have a science-related website and I want to add in it a dark mode. I have added the dark mode but when I click on the dark mode button the body and some other content are working to change but there are some heading like chemistry and biology which is in h2 tag and I have tried to target it but the still not working on it.it will be your kind if you help me in this matter.

here is the code which I have written

```js
//Dark mode javascript code
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

//localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
//const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");

const currentTheme = "dark";

if (currentTheme == "dark") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
} else if (currentTheme == "light") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (prefersDarkScheme.matches) {
    document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
    var theme = document.body.classList.contains("light-theme") ?
      "light" :
      "dark";
  } else {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
    var theme = document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme") ?
      "dark" :
      "light";
  }
  //localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
});
```

```css
 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.abc:hover {
  background: cadetblue;
}

body {
  --text-color: #222;
  --bkg-color: #fff;
}

body.dark-theme {
  --text-color: #eee;
  --bkg-color: #121212;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* defaults to dark theme */
  body {
    --text-color: #eee;
    --bkg-color: #121212;
  }
  body.light-theme {
    --text-color: #222;
    --bkg-color: #fff;
  }
}

body {
  background: var(--bkg-color);
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
b,
a,
strong,
div,
ol,
li,
p {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<button class="btn-toggle abc"><i class="fas fa-adjust" id="abcid"></i></button>

<h1>hello please visit my website and check there</h1>
<p>The header i have target but not working please help me in it</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my website link [you can check my code by visiting the website and inspect it.](https://knownblue.com/)

note: the code is available at the end

[Click to here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip6zT.jpg)

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CRFG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Dark mode javascript code
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn-toggle");
const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

//localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
//const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");

const currentTheme = "dark";

if (currentTheme == "dark") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
} else if (currentTheme == "light") {
  document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
}

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (prefersDarkScheme.matches) {
    document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
    var theme = document.body.classList.contains("light-theme") ?
      "light" :
      "dark";
  } else {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
    var theme = document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme") ?
      "dark" :
      "light";
  }
  //localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
});
```

```css
 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.abc:hover {
  background: cadetblue;
}

body {
  --text-color: #222;
  --bkg-color: #fff;
}

body.dark-theme {
  --text-color: #eee;
  --bkg-color: #121212;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* defaults to dark theme */
  body {
    --text-color: #eee;
    --bkg-color: #121212;
  }
  body.light-theme {
    --text-color: #222;
    --bkg-color: #fff;
  }
}

body {
  background: var(--bkg-color);
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
b,
a,
strong,
div,
ol,
li,
p {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<button class="btn-toggle abc"><i class="fas fa-adjust" id="abcid"></i></button>

<h1>hello please visit my website and check there</h1>
<p>The header i have target but not working please help me in it</p>

</body>
</html>
```